# The rest of the statement is not executed after the while statement completes

Tags: c++

I type in a sentence on the console,the rest of the statement is not executed after the while statement completes.

```
map<string, size_t> stringMap;
string str;
while (cin>>str)
{
    ++stringMap[str];
}
for (const auto &w : stringMap)
{
    cout << w.first << "occurs" << w.second << "times" << endl;
}
```

Comment: why would the while loop ever complete?

Comment: `while (cin>>str)` does not terminate after one sentence. You need to type an end-of-file sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass EOF. To pass EOF you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in Windows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in Unix systems.

Another solution is to type a specific word to exit. Eg:
`while ((cin>>str) != "exit")`.